# Remove partial duplicate tuples in a list based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples like this:

```py
mylist = [
    ('Apple', 'Pass'),
    ('Banana', 'Fail'),
    ('Orange', 'Pass'),
    ('Apple', 'Fail')
]
```

I want to remove tuple `('Apple', 'Fail')` as I have `('Apple', 'Pass')`, meaning remove tuple which has `Fail` if another tuple has `Pass` for `Apple` and so on, so the new list looks like this:

```py
newList = [
    ('Apple', 'Pass'),
    ('Banana', 'Fail'), 
    ('Orange', 'Pass')
]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: If the tuple with `'Fail'` as the second element came first would you still want the same result? Do you want to remove fails if passes exist or do you want to keep the first element with a unique first element?

Comment: Yes, I need `Pass` regardless if it comes first or later. So I need to remove fail if pass exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
# create a set to search for tuples that has Pass
pass_tuples = {e for e, s in mylist if s == 'Pass'}

# keep tuples that are Pass or doesn't have a Pass
newList = [(e, s) for e, s in mylist if s == 'Pass' or e not in pass_tuples]
print(newList)
```

**Output**

```
[('Apple', 'Pass'), ('Banana', 'Fail'), ('Orange', 'Pass')]
```

Basically you want to keep the elements in newList that are `Pass` or that doesn't have a `Pass`.

**Note**: The time complexity of this approach is expected `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# your code goes here
mylist = [
    ('Apple', 'Pass'),
    ('Banana', 'Fail'),
    ('Orange', 'Pass'),
    ('Apple', 'Fail')
]

result = {}
for a, b in mylist:
    if a not in result:
        result[a] = b
    else:
        if result[a] =='Fail' and b=='Pass':
            result[a] = b

mylist =  list(result.items() )
print(mylist)
```

output

```
[('Apple', 'Pass'), ('Banana', 'Fail'), ('Orange', 'Pass')]
```

Answer (score 0):

#create 2 different sets for each fail and pass...

```
setForPass = set()
setForFail = set()

    for i in mylist:
        if i[1] == 'Pass':
            setForPass.add(i[0])
    for i in mylist:
        if i[1] == 'Fail':
            if i[0] in setForPass:
                mylist.remove(i)



output = [('Apple','Pass'), ('Banana','Fail'), ('Orange','Pass')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key-value pairs to build a dict, and use the `max` function to overwrite the current value of a key if the new value is greater (since `Pass` is greater than `Fail` lexicographically; otherwise use a key function). Convert the dict items back to a list of tuples for output:

```
d = {}
for k, v in mylist:
    d[k] = max(v, d.get(k, v))
newList = list(d.items())
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/DiligentOverjoyedPlane